# ParseFile to byte [] C#

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I'm working with parse and i have a `ParseFile`.

I am trying to convert the `ParseFile` to `byte[]` for save it in hdd.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Operator");

    query1.GetAsync ("key").ContinueWith (t1 =>
    {
        OperatorData = t1.Result;
        file = OperatorData.Get<ParseFile>("map");

    });
```

And i want save file in hdd like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("Path",file);
```

How i can do it?
Thank you!

Upd.
file his type  a ParseFile

Comment: what type is your file object? For this to work the "file" object should be byte array! Sorry the actual question is what type is OperatorData!

Comment: ParseFile file;  yep i know and i asking how i can convert ParseFile to byte[]

Comment: What do you want to do with the file, do you need to "load it back in again later" - essentially you will need to "serialize" the object to a byte array as discussed here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used parsed.com, but from their documentation it seems like you have to download the image using the [url](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/P_Parse_ParseFile_Url.htm) specified in the `ParseFile` object.

With .NET you could for instance use the `WebClient` to download it:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(parseFile.Url, @"C:\Temp\YourFile.dat");
```

after that you can retrieve the bytes (or just use the file above directly):

```
var fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\YourFile.dat");
```